# How do I write a program to ask user for 2 cities then return the distance between them

Tags: python

```
       Belfast   Dublin   Cork  Galway                      
Belfast 0        104    266     230                     
Dublin  104      0      161     129                     
Cork    266      161    0       123                     
Galway  230      129    123     0
```

> Declare a 2D array that holds these distances
>
> Declare a list to hold the 4 city names in the same order as table above
>
> Write a program to ask user for 2 cities then return the distance between them
>
> Write a program to convert the 2D array to KM.  Iterate over the entire 2D array and multiply each value by 1.61

So far I have done following:

```
distances = ((0, 104, 266, 230),(104, 0, 161, 129),(266, 161, 0, 123),(230, 129, 123, 0)) 
cities = ((Belfast), (Dublin), (Cork), (Galway))
```

Comment: This sounds like you want us to do your homework for you. What specially is your question? What have you tried? This is way too broad.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [tour] and also read [ask] to get better answers for your questions.

Comment: Given your question it looks like you have done steps 1 and 2. So please show us what code you wrote to have that 2D array and how does look your list that holds the 4 cities. Aslo share what you have done so far with the step 3. And don't worry if it is wrong.

Comment: distances = ((0, 104, 266, 230),(104, 0, 161, 129),(266, 161, 0, 123),(230, 129, 123, 0))
cities = ((Belfast), (Dublin), (Cork), (Galway))

Comment: Are you sure this has to be done in SQL?

Comment: python language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have array distances that contain following data

```
distances = ((0, 104, 266, 230),(104, 0, 161, 129),(266, 161, 0, 123),(230, 129, 123, 0))
```

And you have array

```
cities = ((Belfast), (Dublin), (Cork), (Galway))
```

If you look at cities, then you can address them like `cities[0]` for Belfast `cities[1]` for Dublin and so on.
Same can be done for distances except it has two dimensions so it will be like `distances[0][0]`

BTW: in what language is your program written? Could you put it in your original post?